# Commenting on a closed post should dismiss the flag asking for a comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, closed-questions, moderator-tools, beta-phase

Note how the info to the right of the flag says I've commented

[image: screenshot]

If it knows I've commented, it really shouldn't tell me to comment.  I'm in the habit of commenting immediately after I close, so I can see this happening a lot.  Even for mods who normally comment before closing, the rare occurrence of this flag when they forget or whatever should be dismissed on a comment just like deleting a post clears flags.

I also disagree with the general premise that mods should be nagged instead of being taught up front what to do when closing, but that's a subject for a different post.  There's also the occasional question which is about apples or something, and it's not exactly necessary to leave a comment when closing as off-topic.

As noted in the comments:

**Given the newer clearer close reasons and the help center, sometimes a comment is not even needed. Mods would basically be repeating whats mentioned on the close banner just a few lines below.**

Comment: What the heck is community doing?

Comment: Drinking. Also, summitting. Which is harder than it looks.

Comment: "*There's also the occasional question which is about apples or something...*" - On the Music site?  Awesome =)

Comment: The situation has grown even more absurd with custom close reasons, which are directly intended to save effort explaining our closes in the comments.

Comment: Given the newer clearer close reasons and the help center, sometimes a comment is not even needed. Mods would basically be repeating whats mentioned on the close banner just a few lines below.

Comment: This has always annoyed me.  I generally reject Community's flag if *I* closed the question myself.  Perhaps the little guy will eventually take a hint.

Answer (score 15):

This new behaviour (only on beta sites) is very *very* annoying and quite frankly I don't understand why they're nagging the mods. At the very least, this behaviour could be changed to:

> If a mod closes a question *and* does't leave a comment/there's no
>   other comment *after* 5 minutes from the time of closure, *then* raise
>   a flag asking the mod to explain.

Meanwhile, you get to spend some quality time with Community, declining its flags.

[image]

Comment: It's also triggered by migrated posts where you can't even leave a comment at all since they're locked.

Comment: @Anna True, that's what triggered in mine. We had a small discussion amongst other mods and Rebecca was mulling over excluding migrations and closed as dupes from triggering the flag.