# Please auto-dismiss redundant community flags on questions closed by a moderator

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, moderator-tools, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Commenting on a closed post should dismiss the flag asking for a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109675/commenting-on-a-closed-post-should-dismiss-the-flag-asking-for-a-comment)

On beta sites, when a moderator closes a question and hasn't left a comment, Community raises a flag to ask the moderator to leave a comment. Ok, fine (not like we didn't do it anyway, but if that flag tickles somebody in the right way, why not).

It's kind of ridiculous when the workflow is:

1. Close question.
2. Leave comment.
3. As the page is refreshed when posting the comment, the community flag appears. To tell me to do what I've just done.

Please automatically dismiss the flag when a moderator posts the requested comment.

[image: redundant unicorn]

Comment: wat ಠ_ಠ​​​​​​​​